# RxJava: Filtering a List in an Observable (in place)

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to call an API that retrieves a list of hotels. The response comes back as an `Observable<Response>`. Within the `Response` object there is a `List<HotelAvailability>`, and within the `HotelAvailability` object, there is `HotelInfo` object. If `HotelInfo` is `null`, I want to remove the `HotelAvailability` from the list. I have got halfway with Rx, and then had to default back to a plain-old iterator and while loop. Can anyone help me make this entirely RX? (Note: I am coding on Android and for a relatively low SDK, so JDK8 solutions won't work for me).

```
availabilityApi.getAvailability(hotelName)
            .doOnNext(response -> {
                Iterator<HotelAvailability> hotelAvailabilityIterator = availabilityResponse.hotelAvailabilities().iterator();
                while (hotelAvailabilityIterator.hasNext()) {
                    if (hotelAvailabilityIterator.next().hotelInfo() == null) {
                        hotelAvailabilityIterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps can you check http://pastebin.com/82ZmBAMR. I tried the code in java. so see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the JDK8 API:

```
availabilityApi.getAvailability(hotelName)
        .doOnNext(availabilityResponse ->
           availabilityResponse.hotelAvailabilities().removeIf(
              availability -> availability.hotelInfo() == null
           )
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Edit: Doing it completely in RxJava, but maybe not necessarily better:

```
availabilityApi.getAvailability(hotelName)
        .flatMap(response -> Observable
            .from(availabilityResponse.hotelAvailabilities())
            .filter(availability -> availability.hotelInfo() != null)
            .toList()
            .doOnNext(availabilityResponse::setHotelAvailabilities)
            .map(any -> response)
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: I should have clarified in the question: I'm coding for Android (with a min sdk of 16), so I can't use the JDK8 stuff listed above.

Comment: Ah, that's only available since 24. You could still implement that as a separate utility method for collections, or at least switch from map to doOnNext.

Comment: Thanks: doOnNext() is definitely a little cleaner than map(), I have updated my question with that suggestion. I still feel like the inner `Iterator` and `while` can be done more elegantly... I just can't think how!

Comment: I've added an edit; it's possible, but not necessarily better. Can you add Guava to your project? If so, there's methods there to work with collections that are better than this.

Comment: Your edit works for me, thanks! The bit I was missing was the `flatMap` to get down to the lower level of the hierarchy, and the `map` to get back up to the higher level. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can flatMap your list so you get separate stream events so you can filter them out one by one and then you can aggregate them back into a single list.

```
availabilityApi.getAvailability(hotelName)
        .map(Response::hotelAvailabilities)
        .flatMap(Observable::from)
        .filter(hotelAvailability -> hotelAvailability != null)
        .toList()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

If you want you can even flatMap the list from one single call:

```
flatMap(response -> Observable.from(response.hotelAvailabilities()))
```

Comment: The above code would give me result of type `Observable<List<HotelAvailability>>` rather than an `Observable<Response>`. How do I convert this to an `Observable<Response>` (where the `Response` object contains the filtered list)?